# Create a sim environnement for CNC router

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I already program on ROS but I want to create a 3D simulation of CNC rooter.

Where should I start? Is there example which could be use as base for my project?

My goal is to be able to create path planning and check collisions according to the material on the simulation

My current configuration: ROS1 ROS version :Melodic

Edit :
I use a tuturial to start:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ckSl4MbZLg&t=119s

Here is the code I made to start and generate a "floating camera":
https://github.com/arnauddomes/floating_camera_gazebo/

I try to generate a simple camera that I will move. In gazebo the camera is here but it is moving and is not static.

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26378/create-a-sim-environnement-for-cnc-router/) by [dev4all12358](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40016/dev4all12358/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

you have the camera set to "static" https://github.com/arnauddomes/floating_camera_gazebo/blob/master/src/mybot_description/urdf/mybot.xacro#L15

try removing that line. I would recommend the ConstructSim for tutorials, as well as the official gazebo onces.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2021-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dev4all12358](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40016/dev4all12358/) on 2021-01-21**:
Thank you I will try this